# python-archives Not A Directory Exception While Running Flink Job - PyFlink

Tags: python, virtualenv, apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I'm getting the following exception when running a pyflink application:

- I'm using `start-cluster.sh` to start the flink cluster
- I'm using Python virtual environment to run the flink job (`/root/Python3.6/venv.zip`)
- I've set archive path in the application (`t_env.add_python_archive(archive_path="/root/Python3.6/venv.zip", target_dir=None)`)
- I'm using UDFs and if I take the UDFs out, I won't get this exception and job runs successfully

````
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/root/Python3.6/venv.zip/venv/bin/python" (in directory "/tmp/python-dist-ffa89c4c-527b-49d8-bae3-fd2fd6d3cd67/python-archives"): error=20, Not a directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.flink.python.util.PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.execute(PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.java:193)
    at org.apache.flink.python.util.PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.getPythonUdfRunnerScript(PythonEnvironmentManagerUtils.java:154)
    at org.apache.flink.python.env.beam.ProcessPythonEnvironmentManager.createEnvironment(ProcessPythonEnvironmentManager.java:156)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createPythonExecutionEnvironment(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:395)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.lambda$open$0(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:243)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.lambda$getSharedMemoryResourceForManagedMemory$5(MemoryManager.java:539)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.SharedResources.createResource(SharedResources.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.SharedResources.getOrAllocateSharedResource(SharedResources.java:72)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.getSharedMemoryResourceForManagedMemory(MemoryManager.java:555)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.open(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:246)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:131)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.python.AbstractStatelessFunctionOperator.open(AbstractStatelessFunctionOperator.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.python.scalar.AbstractPythonScalarFunctionOperator.open(AbstractPythonScalarFunctionOperator.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.python.scalar.PythonScalarFunctionOperator.open(PythonScalarFunctionOperator.java:62)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:711)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:687)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:654)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:958)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:927)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:766)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:575)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=20, Not a directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)```
````

Comment: This was a stupid mistake. I had provided the wrong path for python virtual environment. Additionally I had to set the `python.client.executable` to the same path:
```
    t_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string(
        "python.client.executable", "/root/Python3.6/venv/bin/python")
    t_env.get_config().set_python_executable(
        "/root/Python3.6/venv/bin/python")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an ignorant mistake. I had provided the wrong path for python virtual environment. And I didn't need to set the python-archive path in my case as I'm not using that in the code.
Additionally I had to set the `python.client.executable` property point to the same path:

```
t_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string( "python.client.executable", "/root/Python3.6/venv/bin/python") 
t_env.get_config().set_python_executable( "/root/Python3.6/venv/bin/python")
```